# ANTLR4 - keep getting a mismatched input error

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I just started working with Antlr 4. I tried to write a grammar rules for a simple program, but I'm having a difficult time getting it to work.

I am trying to parse a sequence of lines that look like

```
$int a;
$string b;
$int num;
```

However, I keep getting the following error. "line 1:5 mismatched input 'a' expecting IDENTIFIER"

I have tried

- Getting a small repro
- Checking if making something a "fragment" is affecting things

Unfortunately, I am having a difficult time figuring out why this is failing or what exactly to search for to find out more about this. My grammar rules are given below

```
SEPARATION : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+;

fragment 
STARTING_CHARACTER : [a-zA-Z];
fragment 
CHARACTER : [a-zA-Z0-9_];
TERMINATE_CHARACTER : ';';

fragment
TYPE_OR_VAR_IDENTIFIER : STARTING_CHARACTER CHARACTER*;
NAMESPACED_TYPENAME : TYPE_OR_VAR_IDENTIFIER;
IDENTIFIER : TYPE_OR_VAR_IDENTIFIER;

type : '$' NAMESPACED_TYPENAME;

declaration_statement : SEPARATION? type SEPARATION IDENTIFIER SEPARATION? TERMINATE_CHARACTER;

statement : declaration_statement;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching, finally stumbled on to a solution. Looks like this was a similar problem as seen here

[Mismatched input error in simple antlr4 grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970984/mismatched-input-error-in-simple-antlr4-grammar?rq=1)